# submit by Javascript function in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, submit, external

So I have a form.php with 3 input:a(textbox), b(textbox), c(textbox)
Can someone tell me what's this sentence mean and what code should I write to make this happen?

> "c contain the 1st letter of a and b, c is generated on page submit by
>   a javascript function"

^ Can someone give me an simpler, clearer expression for this sentence?

I can write for the "1st letter" part but I'm not sure about the trigger when press submit and that 2nd phrase. Should I

_write javascript in the php? (which doesn't work, I keep getting error, even when I use echo)

or

_have a javascript.js like a External css? (never try before)

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$result= 0;
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"]))
{
  if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
    $result= $_POST["c"];
}}
?>  
<form id="test" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method= "POST">
<p>
a <input type="text" name= "a" value="Alex" />
b <input type="text" name= "b" value="Phan" />
c <input type="text" name= "c" value= "<?php echo $result ?>" />
<input type="submit" name= "submit" onclick= "getc();" />
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getc()
{
 var firsta = document.getElementsByName("a")[0].value.charAt(0);
 var firstb = document.getElementsByName("b")[0].value.charAt(0);
 var c;
 document.getElementsByName("c")[0].value= firsta + firstb;
}
</script>
</form>
```

(This code is an update for the answer)

Turn out the javascript didn't work because I tested it on browser, it worked after I uploaded it on the database. Also it doesn't work when I put it like  ....  ?> either.

Comment: call a js-function onSubmit() (often used for validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use `document.getElementsByName("a")[0].value.charAt(0)` instead of `document.getElementByName("a").value.charAt(0)` the reason is multiple elements can have the same `name`.If your elements are unique, give them all unique `ID` attributes and use `getElementById`

here is the working code

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getc(obj)
{
    var firsta = document.getElementsByName("a")[0].value.charAt(0);

  var firstb = document.getElementsByName("b")[0].value.charAt(0);
  var c;
  obj.value= firsta + firstb;
}
</script>
<form id="test" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method= "POST">
<p>
  a <input type="text"  name= "a" value="Alex" />
  b <input type="text"  name= "b" value="Phan" />
  c <input type="text"  name= "c" onfocus= "getc(this);"/>
</p>
</html>
```

If you want the result on **submitting the form** then
 change

```
c <input type="text"  name= "c" onfocus= "getc(this);"/>
```

To

```
c <input type="text"  name= "c"/>
 <input type="submit"  name= "submit" onclick="getc();" value="submit"/>
```

and in js

change

```
obj.value= firsta + firstb;
```

to

```
document.getElementsByName("c")[0].value=firsta + firstb;
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please **explain** the problem and how your code solves it. Code without an explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: Thanks azhar. I updated the js, but I still can't use them in php.

Comment: using `$_POST['c']` you get the value in php

Comment: so where can I put the javascript?

Comment: @ninjakid in your php file